# PreventDefault on submit if dynamic variable from jQuery plugin is false

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to prevent user from submitting the password form if their user-input password does not met the requirement set by me using a jQuery Plugin. However, my submit handler does not work as intended. please advise. Below is what I have tried.

**update-password.html**

```
<form role="web-form" class="linedform" id="profile-form" action="{% url 'update_password' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %} <div class="form-group togglepassword-right">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <row class="togglepassword-container">
      <input type="checkbox" class="togglepassword-checkbox" id="togglepassword-checkbox"> Show Password
    </row>
    <input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-line" placeholder="Enter Old Password" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group togglepassword-right">
    <label for="new_password">New Password</label>
    <input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="new_password" id="new_password" class="pr-password form-control form-control-line" placeholder="Enter New Password" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" class="form-control form-control-line" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password" />
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-light m-r-10" data-request="ajax-submit" data-target="[role='web-form']" style="cursor:pointer;" id="submitBtn">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
    var passwordRequirement_passed;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log(passwordRequirement_passed, 'listen')

        $('.pr-password').passwordRequirements({}, function (action) {
            if (action.is_passed){
                passwordRequirement_passed = action.is_passed;
            }
            console.log(passwordRequirement_passed, '<passed');
        });

        $('#profile-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            console.log(passwordRequirement_passed, 'submit');
            if (passwordRequirement_passed && passwordRequirement_passed !== true) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the last `if`? If `passwordRequirement_passed` is a boolean, you are trying to check `if(true && false)` ? Why not just use `if(!passwordRequirement_passed)` ?

Comment: @NicolaSpadari please pardon me as I am not well-verse in jquery. I was thinking like python syntax where the first param is to check if its not null, then the second to check if its not true.

Comment: @NicolaSpadari it could be true with anything but `true` hens it's a valid condition, aka `if 123 and not explicit true`

Comment: @stranger doesn't work how exactly? What you need is prevent default `onsubmit` by default and submit the from within your password validation callback function instead.